# Linq results to IEnumerable invalid cast

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

Question for Linq users out there: I'm getting an `InvalidCastexception: Specified cast is not valid` whenever I try to obtain an `IEnumerable` from `revs` after making the Linq query. There database is populated and it *should* be returning values.

Specifically, the error is occurring on the line `List<PDP> rev = revs.ToList<PDP>();`

Any ideas what's going on?

```
short ret;
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    var play = from p in db.PDP
        where p.ID == id
        select p;
    var revs = play.OrderByDescending(p => p.revision);
    List<PDP> rev = revs.ToList();
    var revNum = revs.ToList().Count() > 0 ? rev.First().revision : 0;
    ret = (short)revNum;
}
```

**EDIT**
I've clarified some parts of the code.

**EDIT 2**
`rev` exists as a debugging variable to narrow down where the error was.

The original code was:

```
short ret;
using (GasForecastDataContext db = new GasForecastDataContext())
{
    var play = from p in db.PDP
        where p.Play_ID == play_id
        select p;
    var revs = play.OrderByDescending(p => p.revision);
    var revNum = revs.Count > 0 ? rev.First().revision : 0;
    ret = (short)revNum;
}
```

Comment: Are the datatypes of db.PDP and List<PDP> correct?

Comment: I don't see where you are calling `ToEnumerable`.  Where exactly are you getting the exception?

Comment: @Caspar: That's the same thing; he's just using type inference.  There is no non-generic `ToList()`.

Comment: Is .rev an int, and: is it perhaps nullable?

Comment: @Slaks; right... need read better

Comment: @Marc: .revision (was .rev) is nullable. Is this the problem? How do I get around this then?

Comment: Does changing it to  `var rev = revs.ToList();` help at all?

Comment: All this code for calculating the number of rows corresponding to a given where clause? Also why are you casting the result to `Int16`? What if there are more than 32767 rows in your database corresponding to your criteria? Well, here's what: you get an InvalidCastException.

Comment: You call `ToList()` twice on `revs`. Instead you should call `ToList()` when assigning `revs` making it of type `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` if that is what you want. Also, no need to call `Count()` on a `List<T>`. Just use the `Count` property which is more efficient.

Comment: @Darin: This is a brand new database, and this column is for revision numbers. If there are more than 32767 revisions in this system, it'll need to be an entirely different system. Moreover, the error is being thrown on the `revs.ToList()` line.

Comment: @Swimming why do you need the List anyway? I still don't get that.

Comment: I didn't need the List, I simply needed a IEnumerable to obtain the First element of. Basically, I'm trying to get the entry with the maximal revision with a particular category from a given table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you're declaring the "rev" list variable at all? "Count()" and "First()" are available on IEnumerable interface ( "revs" ).

```
short ret;

using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    var play = from p in db.PDP
        where p.ID == id
        select p;

    var revs = play.OrderByDescending(p => p.revision);

    ret = (short) revs.Count() > 0 ? revs.First().revision : 0;
}
```

Comment: The code you have there is the code I started with. I added rev to try and track down what the error was. For some reason I cannot cast the results from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the elements in `db.PDP` are some type other than `PDP`, or if it is `PDP`, it may be in another namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it still be an IQueryable?

rev could probably be cast as an IEnumberable, but revs is probably still IQueryable.

You might be able to call ToList() on revs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
List<PDP> rev = revs.ToList<PDP>();
```

I just added the type for the generic.

Comment: That won't make any difference; type inference is already doing that.  (or it wouldn't compile)